# How to sync/update a database connection from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

**Problem:**

I need to get data sets from CSV files into SQL Server Express (SSMS v17.6) as efficiently as possible. The data sets update daily into the same CSV files on my local hard drive. Currently using MS Access 2010 (v14.0) as a middleman to aggregate the CSV files into linked tables.

Using the solutions below, the data transfers perfectly into SQL Server and does exactly what I want. But I cannot figure out how to refresh/update/sync the data at the end of each day with the newly added CSV data without having to re-import the entire data set each time.

**Solutions:**

*Upsizing Wizard in MS Access -* This works best in transferring all the tables perfectly to SQL Server databases. I cannot figure out how to update the tables though without deleting and repeating the same steps each day. None of the solutions or links that I have tried have panned out.

*SQL Server Import/Export Wizard -* This works fine also in getting the data over to SSMS one time. But I also cannot figure out how to update/sync this data with the new tables. Another issue is that choosing Microsoft Access as the data source through this method requires a .mdb file. The latest MS Access file formats are .accdb files so I have to save the database in an older .mdb version in order to export it to SQL Server.

**Constraints:**

I have no loyalty towards MS Access. I really am just looking for the most efficient way to get these CSV files consistently into a format where I can perform SQL queries on them. From all I have read, MS Access seems like the best way to do that.

I also have limited coding knowledge so more advanced VBA/C++ solutions will probably go over my head.

**TLDR:**

Trying to get several different daily updating local CSV files into a program where I can run SQL queries on them without having to do a full delete and re-import each day. Currently using MS Access 2010 to SQL Server Express (SSMS v17.6) which fulfills my needs, but does not update daily with the new data without re-importing everything.

Thank you!

Comment: If you feel that an answer has answered your question to your satisfaction, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a staging table strategy to solve this problem.

When it's time to perform the daily update, import all of the data into one or more staging tables. Execute SQL statement to insert rows that exist in the imported data but not in the base data into the base data; similarly, delete rows from the base data that don't exist in the imported data; similarly, update base data rows that have changed values in the imported data.

Use your data dependencies to determine in which order tables should be modified.

I would run all deletes first, then inserts, and finally all updates.

This should be a fun challenge!

**EDIT**

You said:

> I need to get data sets from CSV files into SQL Server Express (SSMS
>   v17.6) as efficiently as possible.

The most efficient way to put data into SQL Server tables is using SQL Bulk Copy.  This can be implemented from the command line, an SSIS job, or through ADO.Net via any .Net language.

You state:

> But I cannot figure out how to refresh/update/sync the data at the end
>   of each day with the newly added CSV data without having to re-import
>   the entire data set each time.

It seems you have two choices:

1. Toss the old data and replace it with the new data
2. Modify the old data so that it comes into alignment with the new data

In order to do number 1 above, you'd simply replace all the existing data with the new data, which you've already said you don't want to do, or at least you don't think you can do this efficiently.  In order to do number 2 above, you have to compare the old data with the new data. In order to compare two sets of data, both sets of data have to be accessible wherever the comparison is to take place. So, you could perform the comparison in SQL Server, but the new data will need to be loaded into the database for comparison purposes.  You can then purge the staging table after the process completes.

Comment: Interesting. Not quite sure that's exactly what will work given that the new data set at the end of each day needs to fully replace all of the old (it is backwards adjusting). So just adding more rows from the new daily data to the legacy data won't work. I'm surprised it's this difficult to find a solution given how easy the update process is going from CSV -> Access -> Excel or CSV -> Excel or Access -> Excel. I figured I must be missing an easy step when replacing Excel with SQL Server as the final destination.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue.  I'll expand my answer and maybe it will prompt further explanation from you.

Answer (score 0):

In thinking further about your issue, it seems the underlying issue is:

> I really am just looking for the most efficient way to get these CSV
>   files consistently into a format where I can perform SQL queries on
>   them.

There exist applications built specifically to allow you to query this type of data.

You may want to have a look at [Log Parser Lizard](https://lizard-labs.com/log_parser_lizard.aspx) or [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/products/splunk-light.html).  These are great tools for querying and digging into data hidden inside flat data files.

Comment: Thanks STL. Log Parser might do the trick. Going to explore that today. Appreciate your time and thoughtful responses.

Answer (score 0):

An Append Query is able to incrementally add additional new records to an existing table.  However the question is whether your starting point data set (CSV) is just new records or whether that data set includes records already in the table.

This is a classic dilemma that needs to be managed in the Append Query set up.

If the CSV includes prior records - then you have to establish the 'new records' data sub set inside the CSV and append just those.  For instance if you have a sequencing field then you can use a > logic from the existing table max.  If that is not there then one would need to do a NOT compare of the table data with the csv data to identify which csv records are not already in the table.

You state you seek something 'more efficient' - but in truth there is nothing more efficient than a wholesale delete of all records and write of all records.  Most of the time one can't do that - but if you can I would just stick with it.

Comment: Thank you Cahaba. After evaluating a lot of different options I think I would agree with your final statement. Appreciate your time.